# Jvm crash when second call to the callback happens

Tags: java, callback, jvm, jna

I using JNA to call native library

My callback interface

```
public interface PPAEvent extends Callback{
    void callback(int eventCode, int opCode, String Data);
}
```

I have a callback implementation of this

```
public class PPAEventImpl implements PPAEvent{

    public void callback(int eventCode, int opCode, String Data) {
        System.out.println("eventCode : "+eventCode);
        System.out.println("opCode : "+opCode);
        System.out.println("Data : "+Data);
    }
}
```

and library class like

```
public interface PAapiMapping extends Library{

    int PAHandShake( int lOperationCode, String sServerAddress, Callback pEventFunc);

    int PAControl(String sData);

    int PARequest(int lOperationCode, String sInputData);

}
```

and I am calling the above library methods..something like

```
PAapiMapping PAapi = (PAapiMapping) Native.load("PAapi", PAapiMapping.class);
PPAEventImpl pPAEvent = new PPAEventImpl();
int result1 = PAapi.PAHandShake(1, "ip", paEventstatic);
System.out.println("result1 : " + result1);
int result2 = PAapi.PAControl(getXML());
System.out.println("result2 : " + result2);
int result3 = PAapi.PARequest(19, "");
System.out.println("result3 : " + result3);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
System.out.println("Execution over");
```

What i understand from the 3rd party library documentation is that the method(like PARequest) that i am calling will have multiple call to the callback method
The callback method is executed once then the JVM crashes. I am new to JNA and dont know what i am doing wrong. Basically what i want is the same callback to handle all the events.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the presented code is, that the callback is not held by a hard reference:

```
PAapiMapping PAapi = (PAapiMapping) Native.load("PAapi", PAapiMapping.class);
PPAEventImpl pPAEvent = new PPAEventImpl();
int result1 = PAapi.PAHandShake(1, "ip", paEventstatic);
// (1)
System.out.println("result1 : " + result1);
// (2)
int result2 = PAapi.PAControl(getXML());
System.out.println("result2 : " + result2);
int result3 = PAapi.PARequest(19, "");
System.out.println("result3 : " + result3);
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
System.out.println("Execution over");
// (3)
// Reference.reachabilityFence(pPAEvent);
```

At point **(1)** the object referenced by *pPAEvent* becomes eligible for GC - the callback is save while it is being passed to native, as the VM can't see through the JNI barier, but after the return of the call to *PAHandShake* the object can be collected.

When **(2)** is reached and the next native call happens, the the callback might still be in place (no GC has happens). In this case the call succeeds or GC has happened and the callback is already been removed. In this case undefined behavior (in most cases a crash) will happen.

You need to ensure, that the call back stays hard referenced. There are various options - the option shown at position **(3)** above works on Java 9+. It will ensure that a hard reference is held till the end. Another option is using a static field to hold the reference - these will normally only collected when the class is unloaded.